# Can't update GridPane

Tags: multithreading, events, javafx-2, javafx, event-dispatch-thread

I have a simple app with a grid ([GridPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)) and a simple toolbar with Start/Stop buttons. My buttons action looks like this:

```
startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            grid.change();
        }
    });
```

and when i click it, the grid changes just like it should. Because Scene graph is not thread-safe and it's rendered only by FX Application Thread, i've placed a service wich should update my grid:

```
private Service task = new Service(){
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        System.out.println("Task created");
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    System.out.println("calling");
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("running");
                           grid.changeGeneration();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1500L);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();  
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
```

When i'm running my app, after pressing the button it gives me this

> Task created
>   calling
>   calling
>   calling
>   running
>   running
>   running

It recomputes the grid model, but it doesn't want to render the view, actually the grid renders by FX App Thread after all Platform.runLater are done, but not after each `running`. Where is my mistake? An how can i make FX App Thread render my grid after each `running`?

**UPDATE:**
Got the solution [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2474848&stqc=true), but still can't fully understand why it refused to work.

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is likely that you publish three `Runnables` in quick succession and the FX queue does not get a chance to actually repaint in between. **Repaints, for the lack of a better name, are not executed immediately but rather added to the end of the event queue**. So basically, your outer loop fires off three `Runnables` and the event queue ends up looking like this: |GridChange|GridChange|GridChange|Repaint|Repaint|Repaint|.

Furthermore, your sleep is actually blocking the event queue - you should never ever invoke `Thread#sleep(...)` within `Platform#runLater(...)`. You're actually blocking all event processing, including repaints and user input, for 3x1500 millis.

Move the `Thread.sleep()` out of the `Runnable` and you'll solve both problems. The event queue will receive the GridChange, have 1.5 seconds to update the UI, receive the next GridChange and so on...

Comment: I've tried to place Thread.sleep() in the Task.call(), that also didn't help.